# Filtering dataframe for previous week dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a dataframe like this--
[image]

Now, I have to filter this data only for the previous week dates (excluding Sat, Sun)

I wrote this Python code-

```
today =  date.today() - timedelta(weeks = 1)
weekday = today.weekday()
prev_week_start = today - timedelta(days = weekday)
for i in range(0,5):
    prev_weekdate = today - timedelta(days = i)
    prev_weekend = prev__weekdate + timedelta(days = 4)
    next_weekstart = prev_weekdate +  timedelta(days = 14)
    next_weekdateend = next_weekstart + timedelta(days = 4)


week_dates = pd.DataFrame({"LastWeekStartDate":pd.to_datetime(['prev_weekdate']),
              "LastWeekEndDate":pd.to_datetime(['prev_weekend']),
              "NextWeekStartDate":pd.to_datetime(['next_weekstart']),
              "NextWeekEndDate":pd.to_datetime(['next_weekdateend'])})
week_dates.head()
```

I am getting the correct dates for all the previous & next week start & end dates with these formulae.

Then I wrote the following code to get my data and filter it for previous week using the above dataframe - week_dates

```
df = pd.read_csv()
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Now to filter rows of my dataframe - df , I wrote-

```
df = df[(df['Date'] >= week_dates.LastWeekStartDate & df['Date'] <= week_dates.LastWeekEndDate)][["Date","Actual Call Volume","Forecasted Call Volume"]]
```

I am getting an error -

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &:'DatetimeArray' and
> 'DateTimeArray'

Please can somebody tell me where I am going wrong or is there any other way to write this code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The values of column 'Date' in my dataframe were being compared with the entire columns of my function week_range(start) table which is not possible. I needed a scalar value to filter my dataframe.
The simplest way to write would be as follows-

```
df = df[(df['Date'] >= prev_week.Prev_week_start[0]) & (df['Date'] >= prev_week.Prev_week_end[0])][["Date","Actual Call Volume","Forecasted Call Volume"]]
```

I simply specified the index for Prev_week_start & Prev_week_end by adding index [0].

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with add `)(` and replaced `][` to `,` and also use `loc` for select first value in `prev_week` DataFrame:

```
df = df.loc[(df['Date'] >= prev_week.loc[0, 'Prev_week_start']) & 
            (df['Date'] <= prev_week.loc[0, 'Prev_week_start']), 
            ["Date","Actual Call Volume","Forecasted Call Volume"]]
```

For simplier solution use:

```
Prev_week_start = date.today() - timedelta(weeks = 1)
Prev_week_end = Prev_week_start + timedelta(days = 4)

df = df.loc[(df['Date'] >= Prev_week_start) & (df['Date'] <= Prev_week_end), 
            ["Date","Actual Call Volume","Forecasted Call Volume"]]
```

Comment: I tried this code . but now getting an error-
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: @UG007 - answer was edited.

Comment: Thanks! I found a simpler way to get the answer- df = df[(df['Date'] >= prev_week.Prev_week_start[0]) & (df['Date'] >= prev_week.Prev_week_end[0])][["Date","Actual Call Volume","Forecasted Call Volume"]]

Comment: @UG007 - yes, it is possible, added to answer.

Comment: The second solution will not work accurately. It is simply giving me dates for7 days back & not considering Monday as the week start date.

Comment: @UG007 - then problem is in `week_range` function, seems broken. At least not used `start` value, `df.Date` is wrong, I guess typos.

Comment: Hi. I have updated the correct code. Thanks for pointing it out.